# get track info of currently playing music in android and ios for delphi

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

Im trying to get title and other available informations of a music playing by a player in android and ios for my Delphi XE5 mobile application! is there anyway i can get access to these? since i couldnt find any documentation about this for delphi!

Comment: I guess the documentation for this, if any, will not be specifically for Delphi. I guess how this is done is different on different platforms. It might even be there is no universal way to do this even on the same platform, since there may be different players, some of which may not even expose this info at all.

Comment: Generally im looking for the normal music player for android and ios. im not targeting any specific players!